# R: Find all combinations without replacement of a sparse matrix

Tags: r, combinations, sparse-matrix, combinatorics

I want to find all possible combinations (without replacement) of a big sparse matrix. Every combination can choose at most one time from each row and column. My goal is to find the combination that maximizes the sum of the chosen entries.

Say I have the following matrix:

```
6 8 . .
. 5 7 .
. 6 . 9
```

There are 4 possible combinations (in terms of i and j): [(1,1),(2,2),(3,4)],[(1,1),(2,3),(3,2)],[(1,2),(2,3),(3,2)],[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]

My outcome should be the sum of entries for each possible combination, where my final goal is to find the combination that maximizes this outcome ([(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)] = 8 + 7 + 9 = 24 in this example).

Edit: here is the full code that generates the sparse matrix of which I want to find the optimal combination:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(haven)
library(Matrix)
library(evd) 

set.seed(12345)

N1 <- 100
M <- 100
I1 <- 10
I2 <- 2
I <- I1 * I2
N <- N1 * I2
J <- 5
p_c_A = 0.02
p_c_B = 0.01
p_0 = 0.05
p_1 = 0.2

dt_workers<- data.table(worker_id = 1:N, 
                           firm_id = sample.int(M, N, replace = TRUE),
                           worker_type = sample.int(I1, N, replace = TRUE)) 

dt_workers[, worker_ethnicity := 1 * (worker_id > N1)]

dt_firms <- data.table(firm_id = 1:M, 
                         firm_type = sample(J) )


sys_util <- matrix(NA, nrow=I1, ncol=J)
for(i in 1:dim(sys_util)[1]){
  for(j in 1:dim(sys_util)[2]){
    sys_util[i,j] <- i * j}
}


joint_surplus

con_A <- matrix(data = runif(N1 * M), nrow = N1, ncol = M)
con_B <- matrix(data = runif(N1 * M), nrow = N1, ncol = M)

con_A <- 1 * (con_A < p_c_A)
con_B <- 1 * (con_B < p_c_B)

p_meet_A <- con_A * p_1 + (1 - con_A) * p_0
p_meet_B <- con_B * p_1 + (1 - con_B) * p_0

meet_A <- matrix(data = runif(N1 * M), nrow = N1, ncol = M)
meet_B <- matrix(data = runif(N1 * M), nrow = N1, ncol = M)

meet_A <- 1* ( meet_A < p_meet_A )
meet_B <- 1* ( meet_B < p_meet_B )

meet <- rbind(meet_A,meet_B)

meet_sparse <- Matrix(meet, sparse = TRUE)
util <- which (meet_sparse>0, arr.ind=T)

n_draws <- dim(util)[1]


mu = 0
sigma = 10
idio = rgumbel(n=n_draws, loc=mu, scale=sigma)

util <- cbind(util,idio)
sys <- vector()
for(k in 1:dim(util)[1]){
  g <- util[k,1]
  f <- util[k,2]
  i <- dt_workers[g, worker_type]
  j <- dt_firms[f, firm_type]
  sys[k] = sys_util[i,j]
}
util <- cbind(util,sys)

total_util = util[,3] + util[,4]

M <- sparseMatrix(
  i = util[,1],
  j = util[,2],
  x = total_util
)
dat <- as.data.frame(summary(M))
dat <-dat[order(dat$i, dat$j),]
rownames(dat) <- NULL
```

Comment: Provide some sample input and output

Comment: Do you just want the max value returned, the matrix positions sampled, or the sampled values returned?

Comment: I want the matrix positions that maximize the sum of values.

Comment: Thought: I think it should be formulated as a Linear Programming problem

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(Matrix)

M <- sparseMatrix(
  i = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  j = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4),
  x = c(6, 8, 5, 7, 6, 9)
)

#> 3 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>             
#> [1,] 6 8 . .
#> [2,] . 5 7 .
#> [3,] . 6 . 9

dat <- as.data.frame(summary(M))

#>   i j x
#> 1 1 1 6
#> 2 1 2 8
#> 3 2 2 5
#> 4 3 2 6
#> 5 2 3 7
#> 6 3 4 9

row_indices <- unique(dat$i)
col_indices <- split(dat$j, dat$i)

#> $`1`
#> [1] 1 2
#> 
#> $`2`
#> [1] 2 3
#> 
#> $`3`
#> [1] 2 4

all_combinations_with_atmost_one_per_row <- do.call(expand.grid, col_indices) 

#>   1 2 3
#> 1 1 2 2
#> 2 2 2 2
#> 3 1 3 2
#> 4 2 3 2
#> 5 1 2 4
#> 6 2 2 4
#> 7 1 3 4
#> 8 2 3 4

more_than_one_per_col <- apply(all_combinations_with_atmost_one_per_row, MARGIN = 1, anyDuplicated)

#> [1] 3 2 0 3 0 2 0 0

combinations <- all_combinations_with_atmost_one_per_row[!more_than_one_per_col, , drop = FALSE]

#>   1 2 3
#> 3 1 3 2
#> 5 1 2 4
#> 7 1 3 4
#> 8 2 3 4

lapply(
  split(combinations, 1:nrow(combinations)),
  function(cols) {
    elements <- data.frame(i = row_indices, j = unlist(cols))
    elements$value <- M[as.matrix(elements)]
    list(elements = elements, sum = sum(elements$value))
  }
)
#> $`1`
#> $`1`$elements
#>   i j value
#> 1 1 1     6
#> 2 2 3     7
#> 3 3 2     6
#> 
#> $`1`$sum
#> [1] 19
#> 
#> 
#> $`2`
#> $`2`$elements
#>   i j value
#> 1 1 1     6
#> 2 2 2     5
#> 3 3 4     9
#> 
#> $`2`$sum
#> [1] 20
#> 
#> 
#> $`3`
#> $`3`$elements
#>   i j value
#> 1 1 1     6
#> 2 2 3     7
#> 3 3 4     9
#> 
#> $`3`$sum
#> [1] 22
#> 
#> 
#> $`4`
#> $`4`$elements
#>   i j value
#> 1 1 2     8
#> 2 2 3     7
#> 3 3 4     9
#> 
#> $`4`$sum
#> [1] 24
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

And the best combination is found with `` res[[which.max(sapply(res, `[[`, "sum"))]] ``

```r
$elements
  i j value
1 1 2     8
2 2 3     7
3 3 4     9

$sum
[1] 24
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! For some reason, your code doesn't work in my simulation. The problem starts in the command col_indices <- split(dat$j, row_indices) where I don't get all the j values for each i for some reason. I attached my full code in the question.

Comment: I think I found the problem in the code. It should be: col_indices <- split(dat$j, dat$i)

Comment: It works fine with very small data sets. When the data is a bit larger, there is not enough memory for the step: all_combinations_with_atmost_one_per_row <- do.call(expand.grid, col_indices). The problem is that it finds many combinations, and then in the next step it eliminates most of them. Is it possible to do it in one stage? Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: My answer doesn/t work anyway. See `M <- sparseMatrix(
  i = c(1, 2, 2),
  j = c(1, 1, 2),
  x = c(1, 3, 1)
)` where the optimal solution is `[(2, 1)]` with a sum of `3`, and I find `[(1, 1), (2, 2)]` with a sum of `2` instead.

Comment: Yes, you need to add the option of no match ([1, 0] in your example) with value 0 ("single" in the terminology of the marriage problem). I guess it is easy to add the option i=0 and j=0 to the basic matrix, but without the restriction that the sum of this raw/column should be less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using linear programming with the help of Aurèle:

```
f.con <- matrix(,nrow = dim(dat)[1],ncol=0)
for(k in 1: N){   
    vec <- 1 * (dat[,1] == k)
    f.con <- cbind(f.con , vec )
}

for(k in 1: M){   
  vec <- 1 * (dat[,2] == k)
  f.con <- cbind(f.con , vec )
}
f.con <- t(f.con)
f.obj <- dat[,3]
f.dir <- rep ("<=", dim(f.con)[1])
f.rhs <- rep (1, dim(f.con)[1])
res = lp (direction = "max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs ,  all.int=TRUE)$solution
```